# How to display image in ImageView

Tags: android, imageview, android-camera, android-imageview, android-image

So I'm trying to display a captured image in an ImageView but for some reason my ImageView stays black. If I choose an image from the drawable-Folder it works. The captured image exists in the right folder too.

The camera-intent:

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, getImageUri());
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
```

with

```
private Uri getImageUri() {
    String CAPTURE_TITLE="3.png";
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/receipts", CAPTURE_TITLE);
    Uri imgUri = Uri.fromFile(file);

    return imgUri;
}
```

These are the things I tried:

1.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST) {
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator + "receipts"+File.separator + "3.jpg");
        ImageView receiptImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.result_image);
        receiptImage.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(file.getAbsolutePath(), 500, 250));
    }
}
```

with

```
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(String path, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight) {
        inSampleSize = Math.round((float)height / (float)reqHeight);
    }

    int expectedWidth = width / inSampleSize;

    if (expectedWidth > reqWidth) {
        inSampleSize = Math.round((float)width / (float)reqWidth);
    }


    options.inSampleSize = inSampleSize;

    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

    return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
}
```

I modified my method call above so it delivers a File instead of an Uri for the method above.

2.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST) {
        ImageView receiptImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.result_image);

        Uri receiptUri = Uri.parse("/receipts/3.png");

        try {
            InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(receiptUri);
            Drawable drawable = Drawable.createFromStream(inputStream, null);
            receiptImage .setImageDrawable(drawable);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
    }
}
```

3.

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST) {
        ImageView receiptImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.result_image);
        receiptImage.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/receipts/3.png"));  
    }
}
```

I tried to use `Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");` too but my app crashed right after the camera app was closed. For some reason data returns null then. This is the crash log:

```
10-14 10:38:10.728  32275-32275/com.example.debt E/AndroidRuntime? FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.example.debt/com.example.debt.ScanReceiptActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3184)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3227)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:138)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1252)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4872)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.debt.ScanReceiptActivity.onActivityResult(ScanReceiptActivity.java:78)
            at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5375)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3180)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3227)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:138)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1252)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4872)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I ran the app on an LG P880.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing `CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST` to `CAMERA_REQUEST`

```
Intent cameraIntent=new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, getImageUri());

startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
```

after capturing the image you will get the result in the ActivtyResult.

```
if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST) {  
    Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); 
}
```

Comment: I defined that variable at the top of my Activity: `private static final int CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST = 1;`. I do get into that if-branch too. I tested that. If I use `Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");` my app crashes right after the camera-app is closed.

Comment: @timbotombo post your log from that crash and dont use `CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST` that you defined try it with `CAMERA_REQUEST` see if it makes a difference

Comment: @timbotombo also try `startActivtyForResult(cameraIntent, 1337)`

Comment: When I didn't define `CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST` or `CAMERA_REQUEST` that variable couldn't be resolved. I've added the crash report in my post above. I tested setting up an ImageView with an image from my phone which wasn't just captured and realized it didn't work either - black ImageView there too. So I'm assuming that that problem isn't camera-related at all.